# Should you create separate tables for fixed options for a column?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

As shown below, in multiple places in my DB Design I am creating tables for "options" if you will. Example, RFP Stages. Which would hold things like "Complete", "Bidding", etc.

I'm doing this because it was recommended to me at one point in a question that was deleted. Is this the proper way to do this? Or should I just store these options as text, given there is only 5 or so possibilities?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any "options" table in that ER diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correct. I think you have at least 4 alternatives.

1. ENUM https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html
2. Table lookup
3. Local lookup
4. Plain Text

Personally I prefer table lookup with id and name. You store only the ID. So you have to join tables when fetching. It is easier to add or delete options. And it is easier to search for status 1. And the footprint will be smaller.

Comment: What's a "local lookup"?

Comment: At client side, you can do a list (php or similar) that you lookup and select from. I use this when the options are static.

Comment: Or a Variable List you import into React would be an example of local lookup, something I considered but this seemed like a better practice.

Comment: @MattWeber I treat local lookup exact like a table lookup with id and name.